# Connecting the server domain name to local machines through intranet

Tags: 12.04, networking, server, intranet

I have a `Ubuntu 12.04` server. The requirement is that the domain name of the server should be accessible to my other local machines through intranet(LAN). If the domain name which i have given for the server is typed in the browser of any local machine, it should get a secure connection with my Ubuntu server. Can anyone guide me the logic for this setup.

Answer (score 1):

If you already have a LAN, you very likely have DHCP and DNS set up on a machine. The only thing you then have to do is to add the hostname and the IP address of the new machine to the DNS server.

The other option is that all of your local machines have to add the hostname and IP address of the new machine to their `/etc/hosts` file. This can work for small networks with static IP addresses, but is not common practice any more.

You can find your DHCP server using:

```
nmap --script broadcast-dhcp-discover -e eth0
```

Where `eth0` is your ethernet device. (Yours could be different, but is unlikely on Ubuntu 12.04, use `ifconfig` to find out.)

The IP address of the DHCP server will be listed after `Server Identifier:`

You can find your DNS server(s) in your `/etc/resolv.conf` file after `nameserver`. You can also run:

```
nm-tool | grep DNS
```

Comment: I tried the above implementation. The ethernet device is `eth1`, i found out that once i execute `nmap --script broadcast-dhcp-discover -e eth0` i am getting a message saying `NSE: failed to initialize the script engine:
/usr/share/nmap/nse_main.lua:464: 'broadcast-dhcp-discover' did not match a category, filename, or directory`. Also `nm-tool | grep DNS` returns nothing. Can you guide me how to configure the above 2 limitations.

Comment: Seems like you don't have that particular script in your version of nmap. Mine is version `6.40` (use: `nmap --version`). Use `locate nse | grep script` to find all available scripts. There might be another script that you use to find your DHCP server.  You should be able to use `route -n` to find your gateway, which is very likely where your DHCP service is located. Is this a home-network with only a modem/router or is it a business network with dedicated servers for DHCP, DNS and Proxy services?